# To get short-term visa for UK

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, paperwork

I am an Indian National. Right now I am travelling USA for visiting purposes. In a couple of weeks I'll return to my home country but just now I heard from my friend in UK. She is facing a divorce case and needs me in UK as she wants to make me a witness in a court hearing. I have the solid evidence which will help her to win the case and otherwise she'll loose her kids and everything and she'll be on the road. So the situation is I have to go via UK on my way home.

Can I apply for a UK visa from USA?
If yes, then in which category do I have to apply?
And what documents do I need?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can apply for a UK visa from the USA.

For the purpose cited, you need a Standard Visitor visa.

You should carefully review the [general information for applying for a Standard Visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview), and then the [special instructions for applying within the USA](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa).

Comment: My friend from UK, she wants to sponsor me as the court hearing is not far so what documents she needed in sponsorship??

Comment: @Swami that's a different question. But the answer should be found by **carefully** reading the sites linked.